# How to change Twitter follow button width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I know this has been asked in other threads but those answers didn't suit my case. If you embed the twitter follow button from here:

https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

the JS replaces the link with an iframe:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1360366574.html#_=1360791644346&amp;count=horizontal&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fsearch%2Fcats&amp;size=m&amp;text=Search%20Results%20for%20%22cats%22%20on%20Foo&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fsearch%2Fcats" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" style="width: 109px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button" data-twttr-rendered="true"></iframe>
```

As you can see the width is set as an inline style. I know I can overide this with something like:

```
.twitter-share-button { width: 80px !important; }
```

for example but I don't want to do that because what if the share count increases to a very large number on a particular content page. Then the share count will be obscured by the minimum width.

Is there a way to tell twitter to size the returning iframe according to the share count that is inside, so that it is no bigger than the minimum required width it needs to be?

I know Facebook accepts the desired width via data attributes `data-width` I believe and this can be set to auto to get the type of behavior I am asking for above. Does twitter offer anything similar for their share button?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LxbJ/)

Comment: The link is in an iframe, you can not do anything in your CSS to change it. You would have to look to see if twitter lets you change the styles with some api. Does setting the width of the iframe change the button size?

Comment: I have the same issue with the Twitter follow button. The JS code produces HTML with an inline width that is bigger than the actual button. This makes precise positioning impossible. Overriding the width with `!important` is not a sustainable solution as the follower count might grow, leading the button to become bigger and thus being 'chopped off'. Anyone found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `width`, set a `min-width`:

```
.twitter-share-button { min-width: 80px !important; width: auto !important;}
```

Comment: my problem is that the default width itself is too large. Setting a min width wouldn't help.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link or explain what problem you're trying to solve that requires the width of the button to be dynamic.

Comment: @ZakAngelle trying to make a group of buttons from various social-whatever-vendors that will live side by side in a single line without unsightly gaps/overflows caused by fixed spacing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known problem (see [this Dev Twitter thread](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11405)) that has been waiting for an effective solution for almost 2 years, as of now. At the moment there seems to be no *clean* way to let the button width match its actual content.
One could fiddle with some custom javascript, but then again in the end you hit the IFrame/CORS wall if you try to manipulate the IFrame.

Comment: Quite pathetic that a company like Twitter is taking so long on this.

Comment: Until now, as a workaround, I just set the `width` on the container element.